# Putting a case statement in max() function and where statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this case statement where I get the modified stop_time column as Stop_TimeNEW

```
select 
        case
            when Stop_Time is null then sysdate
            else Stop_Time
        end as Stop_TimeNEW
from TEMPTABLE;
```

And I would like to use that Stop_TimeNEW value in this select statement, whenever it says 'Stop_Time'.

```
Select sum(minutes)
 From (
        Select Distinct 
               B.DateR1
              ,B.DateR2
              , (((extract(DAY FROM DateR2-DateR1)*24*60*60)+ 
                (extract(HOUR FROM DateR2-DateR1)*60*60)+
                (extract(MINUTE FROM DateR2-DateR1)*60)+
                extract(SECOND FROM DateR2-DateR1)))/60 as minutes
         From TempTable A
         Cross Apply (
                      Select
                            Min(Start_Time) as DateR1
                            ,max(Stop_Time) as DateR2
                       From  TempTable 
                       Where Start_Time <= A.Stop_Time and Stop_Time >= A.Start_Time 
                     ) B
 ) A
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work

```
Select sum(minutes)
 From (
        Select Distinct 
               B.DateR1
              ,B.DateR2
              , (((extract(DAY FROM DateR2-DateR1)*24*60*60)+ 
                (extract(HOUR FROM DateR2-DateR1)*60*60)+
                (extract(MINUTE FROM DateR2-DateR1)*60)+
                extract(SECOND FROM DateR2-DateR1)))/60 as minutes
         From TempTable A
         Cross Apply (
                      Select
                            case
                                when Stop_Time is null then sysdate
                                else Stop_Time
                             end as Stop_TimeNEW,
                            Min(Start_Time) as DateR1
                            ,max(Stop_TimeNEW) as DateR2
                       From  TempTable 
                       Where Start_Time <= A.Stop_TimeNEW and Stop_TimeNEW >= A.Start_Time 
                     ) B
 ) A
```

AND

```
Cross Apply (
                      Select
                            case
                                when Stop_Time is null then sysdate
                                else Stop_Time
                             end as Stop_TimeNEW,
                            Min(Start_Time) as DateR1
                            ,max(case
                                when Stop_Time is null then sysdate
                                else Stop_Time
                             end as Stop_TimeNEW) as DateR2
                       From  TempTable 
                       Where Start_Time <= (select case
                                when Stop_Time is null then sysdate
                                else Stop_Time
                             end as Stop_TimeNEW from a) and (select case
                                when Stop_Time is null then sysdate
                                else Stop_Time
                             end as Stop_TimeNEW from temptable) >= A.Start_Time 
                     ) B
```

Was wondering if anyone could assist?

Comment: This is not Oracle syntax. Maybe you are using SQL Server?

Comment: no i'm using oracle. the first two syntax did work in sql developer

Comment: @GMB, Starting 12C, Oracle too support CROSS APPLY.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: thanks - learning something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a NVL function (which handles the null value). Try below query -

```
Select sum(minutes)
 From (
        Select Distinct 
               B.DateR1
              ,B.DateR2
              , (((extract(DAY FROM DateR2-DateR1)*24*60*60)+ 
                (extract(HOUR FROM DateR2-DateR1)*60*60)+
                (extract(MINUTE FROM DateR2-DateR1)*60)+
                extract(SECOND FROM DateR2-DateR1)))/60 as minutes
         From TempTable A
         Cross Apply (
                      Select
                            Min(Start_Time) as DateR1
                            ,MAX(NVL(Stop_Time, sysdate)) as DateR2
                       From  TempTable 
                       Where Start_Time <= A.Stop_Time and Stop_Time >= A.Start_Time 
                     ) B
 ) A
```

Comment: hm sorry, i'm not sure if you were understanding my question properly. but i need to replace the Stop_Time variable with that case statement. not sure if the nvl will address this?

Comment: Now I understand your problem. You need NVL inside max function rather than outside MAX function. Please try it and let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

**Select

CASE WHEN Stop_Time is null then sysdate

else Stop_Time

end as Stop_TimeNEW,
            ......
From  TempTable

Where Start_Time <= A.Stop_TimeNEW and Stop_TimeNEW >= A.Start_Time**

won't work as in order of execution 'Where' clause is executed before SELECT and AS, that means that while WHERE is being executed in your code, it doesn't even know that Stop_TimeNEW is created yet. 
I suggest you could use a subquery to do the same

`SELECT Stop_TimeNEW
        ,Min(Start_Time) as DateR1
        ,max(Stop_TimeNEW) as DateR2 
FROM
    (Select A.*,
            CASE WHEN Stop_Time is null then sysdate
                  ELSE Stop_Time
                END AS Stop_TimeNEW
                       From  TempTable A)
 Where Start_Time <= A.Stop_TimeNEW and Stop_TimeNEW >= A.Start_Time`